# Trying to ping google and if no respons disable/enable interface

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, ping, netsh

When I startup my computer I don't always have internet right away. I've tried many things but never found a definitive solution to my problem. So what I do now is ping a host. If I can't reach it then I disable and enable my network card.

I have a little batch file that disable and enable the interface.
But I would like to create a batch file that launches on startup, tests my ping and if no response then will disable/enable my network interface.

Is this code correct?

```
@echo on
set "host=google.com"

ping -n 1 "%host%" | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms"

if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo Success.
) else (
    set "params=%*"
    cd /d "%~dp0" && ( if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ) && fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% 1>nul 2>nul || (  echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) : UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k cd ""%~sdp0"" && %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && exit /B )
    @echo on
    netsh interface set interface "Ethernet 2" DISABLED
    timeout /t 10
    netsh interface set interface "Ethernet 2" ENABLED
)
```

I've tried it once but didn't seem to see the ping action or anything on my command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "host=google.com"
set "requests=4"
set "replies=0"

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('ping -n %requests% %host%') do (
    echo %%A
    echo(%%~A | find "Reply" >nul 2>nul && set /a "replies+=1"
)

if %requests% equ %replies% (
    echo Success.
) else (
    cd /d "%~dp0" && (
        if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

        net session 1>nul 2>nul || (
            (
                echo Set UAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application"^)
                echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k cd ""%~dp0"" && ""%~f0"" %*", "", "runas", 1
            ) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

            "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
            exit /b 0
        )
    )

    netsh interface set interface "Ethernet 2" DISABLED
    timeout /t 10
    netsh interface set interface "Ethernet 2" ENABLED
)
```

Perhaps you do not see the ping work as `-n 1` can be quick
to `ping` if the connection is OK. The `findstr` pattern
seems reasonable and detects i.e. `9ms`.

I changed the `ping` to `-n %requests%` so that success is
based on the set number of requests to equal the number of
replies to `find` the word `Reply`. If not requests equal
replies, then regarded as fail. If you do not want to view
the output of `ping`, then remove the line `echo %%A`.

Adjusted the VBScript code with quoting and the modifiers
changed a little. I unpacked the code to multi-line to
make it easier to view.

Changed `fsutil dirty query %systemdrive%` to `net session`
for admin user detection.

Not sure why you need to set the current directory though
I decided just to leave them in. Perhaps you were writing
`getadmin.vbs` to the current directory and thus was a
need.